# Upgrading from Microsoft 2013 to 2016

Tags: microsoft-office, upgrade

When updating from Microsoft Office 2013 to 2016, do I have to uninstall Microsoft Office 2013 first or not? The reason I ask is because Microsoft Office 2013 is still showing in my list of installed application (i.e. in Revo Uninstaller) and it's full size of 1.87GB, after doing n "upgrade" from 2013 to 2016. I assumed that it would replace it totally (or at least traces of the corresponding Applications between the two versions).

Comment: I appreciate the prompt reply, and think I just figured this out: the size of the content in the folder "Office15" folder located in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office is 307MB and the size of the new folder "Office16" is 1.48GB, which is an indication of the merger of the two versions. But when I check under "Installed Updates" in Programs and Features (in the Control Panel), there's only MS Office 2016 components/updates and there is no trace of 2013 components, while the Programs & Features windows (like Revo) shows both versions of the suite. So how do explain that? I'm confused.

Answer (score 1):

What happens, or has to happen, to Office 2013 when you install 2016 depends on the versions of product you installed.

Most consumer based packages use click-to-run technology. You can’t have two different versions of office click-to-run installed side by side. It will uninstall 2013 or fail to continue.

There is also an MSI version of Office, that is available under volume license with Microsoft. This is not available to home users. If it was installed, it would probably not be a legitimate copy.

You can have two different versions of two different types of Office. Like office 2013 MSI installed along side Office 2016 click-to-run.

At this point, I would suggest uninstalling any leftover 2013 components from programs & features. If you have trouble, you can use the steps found [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/uninstall-office-from-a-pc-9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8) to cleanly remove office and then you can reinstall the version you want fresh.

Here’s a little more information about the different versions of office:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/deva/2015/12/09/it-pros-can-i-use-office-2013-side-by-side-with-office-2016/